Why does addEventListener not work like jQuery
I tried to get the e.target of 3 buttons through addEventListener but it doesn't work with javascript but works fine with jquery. Can you explain this to me?


let cards = [{
  title: 'selin',
  price: 20000
}, {
  title: 'young',
  price: 30000
}, {
  title: 'hanoe',
  price: 10000
}]

for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  var cards_templte = `
    <div class="card col-md-4" >
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">${cards[i].title}</h5>
         <p class="card-text">${cards[i].price}</p>
         <button class="store-btn">구매</button>
       </div>
   </div>`
  document.querySelector('.row').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', cards_templte);
}

document.querySelector('.store-btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
})
<div class="row"></div>




The issue here is that document.querySelector('.store-btn') selects only the first element with the class .store-btn. You need querySelectorAll. jQuery works because it selects ALL the elements

@AntonijaŠimić They need to delegate. document.querySelector('.row').addEventListener('click', (e) => console.log(e.target.closest('.card').querySelector('.card-title').textContent))

"Why does addEventListener not work like jQuery" - err, because it's not jquery?

Always feel free to read the documentation of functions you're using. MDN docs - querySelector. The first sentence tells you that it returns only the first element. Also browsers have developer tools, search how to use them. You can look at variable values, stop execution, make log entries. This way you can see what the return value is.
